# Repeat Vim fold command (e.g. zfat: fold a tag)

Tags: vim, folding

Is there a way to repeat a fold command I just executed? For example, say I am folding away a few tags with "zfat", how can I repeat the fold command I just executed without typing it again in its entirety?

Comment: are you familiar with vim macros?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other option (besides mapping, as mention by lya):

```
 qqzfatq
```

Now `@q` repeats that. `@@` repeats the last-used macro so you could actually do `@@j@@j@@j@@` or similar to repeat more often.

Alternatively, you can include the motion (if it was necessary), for example assuming `j` is the motion to move to the next tag to be folded:

```
 qqzfatjq
```

Now, `10@q` folds 10 successive tags

Comment: You could type `qqzfatjq` to include `j` in the macro too

Comment: Maybe he left a tab open and didn't refresh.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way as long as I know.
Maybe you can use macros or key mapping, i.g.

```
:map <F2> zfat
```

Then just press 'F2' to execute 'zfat'.